# what is a homomorphism of (op)fibrations?

Tags: category-theory

I am reading the book "Category Theory for Computing Science" about fibrations, and am having trouble understanding what a "homomrophism of opfibrations" is in 12.3.4 FI-2.

> FI-2 If $\zeta: (P,\kappa) \rightarrow (P',\kappa')$ is a homomorphism
>   of optifibrations,  $F\zeta: F(P,\kappa) \rightarrow F(P',\kappa')$ is
>   the natural transformation ..

There isn't much detail about how $\zeta$ is defined. 
I am confused because an (op)fibration is $P: E \rightarrow C $ is a **functor** from categories $E$ to $C$ by definition.

Is there a natural way to define a homomorphism between any two functors? (It seems to me from the quote that there is a natural definition of $\zeta$ which I missed, and the authors then extended $\zeta$ to a natural transformation $F\zeta$.)

A homomorphism preserves some structures. What exactly does a homomorphism from a functor/fibration $P$ to another functor preserve? More specifically, how exactly is the mapping $\zeta$ defined?

Comment: You can find a short summary at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibred_category#Cartesian_morphisms_and_functors Briefly, an **(op)cartesian functor** between from a functor $E_1\xrightarrow{p_1}C$  to a functor $E_2\xrightarrow{p_2}C$ is a thid functor $E_1\xrightarrow{F} E_2$ so that a) $p_2\circ F=p_1$ and b) it takes (op)-$p_1$-cartesian morphisms to (op)-$p_2$-cartesian morphisms.